# creating text file in VB.NET adding extra line

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create text file with the code below; but there is always an extra line at the end that I cannot get rid of. Is there any way to modify this code to write the text file without the last line?? Help appreciated:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MekdamFile As String
    MekdamFile = "C:\TEMP\MEKDAM.txt"
    Dim dones As New List(Of String)
    For i = 1 To 10
        dones.Add("test test " & i)
    Next
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(MekdamFile)
        For Each i As String In dones
            sw.WriteLine(i)
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks for help in advance...

Comment: How does your result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified a bit:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   File.WriteAllText("C:\TEMP\MEKDAM.txt", [String].Join( _
       Environment.NewLine, _
       Enumerable.Range(1, 10).[Select](Function(i) "Test test" + Cstr(i))))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

StreamWriter.WriteLine always writes a line terminator.

On the last iteration of the loop you could use sw.Write instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling WriteLINE, so whatever you pass into it will be appended with a newline character sequence.

If you don't want to write the newline, use Write instead of WriteLine. Of course, you should then append the newline yourself for all lines except the last.

Alternatively, for a small text, just build the whole text, then trim the end of it and write it at once:

```
Dim sb As new StringBuilder();
For i = 1 To 10
    sb.AppendLine("line " + i);
Next
File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString().TrimEnd());
```